# How to unprotect route in next js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, middleware

so I want to unprotect the login page and here is my folder structure:

[image]

here is my middleware:

```js
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  if (req.pathname === "login") {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

so how do I make it so the middleware does not apply to login.js.

**Edit**: it now returns `[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies`

code for this project is [here](https://github.com/ShahabAthar25/google-docs-mern/tree/main/frontend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I solved the error I was not getting the pathname from `req.nextUrl` and here is the correct code:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (pathname == "/login" && !token) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `request` is for the `/login` page itself, and bail early.

Checkout all properties on [NextRequest](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server) that are available.

```js
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  if( req.pathname === 'login'){
      return NextResponse.next();
  }
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Comment: i have added your solution but now it gives me ```localhost redirected you too many times.``` error

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted answer helped me a lot. I'm adding my solution because I had to make some modifications.

I used `[...nextauth].js` file with `jwt` and `session` callbacks and when I used the solution from accepted answer, I was getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS` cycle. My solution was to add a few more URLs:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

export default async function middleware(req, ev) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET });

  if ((pathname == "/api/auth/signin" || pathname == "/favicon.ico" || pathname == "/api/auth/callback/credentials") && !token) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/api/auth/signin', req.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```